# Make progress bars responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these `progress bars` which are suppose to work as ratings and they look good:
[image]

I have applied some `CSS` and I change their width with `JavaScript` by reading values from text files.
But are not responsive at all and whenever the window is resized:
[image]

`HTML`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="second-part">

              <div class="row">
                    <div class="side">
                      <div>5 stars</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle">
                      <div class="bar-container">
                        <div class="bar11" style="width: 10% ; height: 18px; background-color: gold;"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side right">
                      <div class="p11">150</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                      <div>4 stars</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle">
                      <div class="bar-container">
                        <div class="bar12" style="width: 10% ; height: 18px; background-color: gold;"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side right">
                      <div class="p12">63</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                      <div>3 stars</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle">
                      <div class="bar-container">
                        <div class="bar13" style="width: 10% ; height: 18px; background-color: gold;"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side right">
                      <div class="p13">15</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                      <div>2 stars</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle">
                      <div class="bar-container">
                        <div class="bar14" style="width: 10% ; height: 18px; background-color: gold;"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side right">
                      <div class="p14">6</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                      <div>1 star</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middle">
                      <div class="bar-container">
                        <div class="bar15" style="width: 10% ; height: 18px; background-color: gold;"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side right">
                      <div class="p15">20</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

`CSS`:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Three column layout */
.side {

        float: left;
        width: 15%;
        margin-top:10px;
    }

    .middle {
        margin-top:10px;
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
    }

    /* Place text to the right */
    .right {
        text-align: left;

    }


    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }


    /* The bar container */
    .bar-container {
        width: 90%;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
    /* Responsive layout - make the columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        .side, .middle {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .right {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

`JavaScript` to change progress bar width:

```
var par1 = 4;
  for(var i = 10; i < 16; i++) {
    $('.p' + (i+1)).text(table[0][par1]);
    $('.bar' + (i+1)).css("width", table[0][par1]);
    par1++;
  }
```

How could I make it more responsive? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I can't recreate your issue. it works https://jsfiddle.net/hgtfjdnr/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using css flexbox, so the items wrap instead of overlap when the page is resized. You could use media queries with this to adjust the size of the items and container so they don't overlap/wrap. This site has a good explanation of flexbox: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/%22A%20Guide%20to%20Flexbox%22).